# D3 remove comma delimiters for thousands

Tags: parsing, d3.js, time, delimiter

I have a .json with 3 columns where one of them is 'Year'. The column contains only years. No dates!.

When I am graphing it on the 'x' axis the years come out with a comma delimiter for thousands.

So in the .json the date is this format :"Year":1990
and on the 'x' axis it comes out like that 1,990

I have been trying to figure out how to parse the year but I have no luck so far. I have tried the following:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%y").parse

var x = d3.time.scale()
.range([0, width]);

//further down

d3.json("waterData.json", function(error, json) {

// Attach Data
var data = json.data;

// Select Data for X and Y
var axis1 = 'Year'; 
var axis2 = 'Ratio'

// Convert String into Numbers
data.forEach(function(d) {

///axis1 = parseDate(axis1);

d[axis1] = +d[axis1]
d[axis2] = +d[axis2]
});

 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[axis1]; }));
 y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[axis2]; }));


 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height+10) + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
 .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("x", width)
  .attr("y", -40)
  .text(axis1)

 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate("+ -10 + "," + 0 + ")")
  .call(yAxis)
 .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .style("fill", "#666")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(axis2)
```

Any suggestions of how to get rid of the comma delimiter. Or to figure out how to parse the date.

Comment: It looks like you're not actually using your `parseDate` function. Try `d[axis1] = parseDate(d[axis1])`.

Comment: I am using it, or at least I am trying the 5th line bottom-top. Thank you for the suggestion, but this does not work.

Comment: You're using it in the wrong place. Is this your complete code?

Comment: No it is not the complete code.

Comment: So how are you passing these values to the scale?

Comment: I hope that is the part that you were asking for.

Comment: Just noticed that your format specifier has a lowercase y instead of an uppercase one. Could you try changing that and then parse again as I've suggested?

Comment: I tried that one and no difference. I am still not sure where you are suggesting to call the parser

Comment: You need to call the parser where you want to parse the value, i.e. +d[axis1].

Comment: well I did that the first time you suggested it and it did not work. I am sure I am missing something important.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should add `.tickFormat(d3.format("d"))` to your xAxis:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.format("d"));
```

Comment: Note that this makes you lose decimal accuracy